# Can't link a C shared object to a C++ program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

I am trying to write a makefile for a project. The project involves a test program that defines a main function written in C++11 that is supposed to call a shared object library written in c99 and run some tests.

My makefile successfully compiles the c99 library and produces "libhanoi.so".

When I try to link the C99 library to the C++11 part, I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -L. -lhanoi -o main tests/testing.cpp tests/main.cpp
/tmp/cctHQTcW.o: In function `binarion_constructor(unsigned long*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `binarion64_t'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'tests' failed
make: *** [tests] Error 1
```

However, the output of "nm -C libhanoi.so" shows that the binarion64_t function is being exported by libhanoi.so:

```
0000000000000610 T binarion64_t(long long, long long)
```

When I introduce a typo into the name of libhanoi.so, it introduces an error saying it can't find libhanoi.so.

So it must be able to find libhanoi.so and libhanoi.so is exporting the unimplemented function in main.cpp, yet it still is giving an undefined reference. What's going on?

Minimal example:

hanoi.h:

```
#ifndef HANOI_H
#define HANOI_H

#include <inttypes.h>

// binarion (base -1+i) constructor
uint64_t binarion64_t(long long A, long long B);


#endif // HANOI_H
```

binarion.c:

```
#include "hanoi.h"

uint64_t binarion64_t(long long A,long long B){
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
#include "hanoi.h"
};

uint64_t binarion_constructor(uint64_t * args){
   return binarion64_t(args[0], args[1]);
}

int main(void){
   return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -std=c99 -c binarion.c
g++ -std=c99 -shared -o libhanoi.so binarion.o -lm
g++ -std=gnu++11 -L. -lhanoi -o main main.cpp
```

output:

```
/tmp/ccjoRmCg.o: In function `binarion_constructor(unsigned long*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `binarion64_t'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT:

The commands I'm running are:

```
gcc -std=c99 -c binarion.c
gcc -std=c99 -shared -o libhanoi.so binarion.o -lm
g++ -std=gnu++11 -L. -lhanoi -o main main.cpp
```

The files are exactly the ones in the question. The output of "readelf -s libhanoi.so | grep binarion" is:

```
12: 0000000000000660    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 binarion64_t
33: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS binarion.c
46: 0000000000000660    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 binarion64_t
```

and the output of "g++ -std=gnu++11 -L. -lhanoi -o main main.cpp" is:

```
/tmp/cczfgY8M.o: In function `binarion_constructor(unsigned long*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `binarion64_t'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: When including a C header in C++ code, you have to wrap the inclusion into `extern "C" { }`. Otherwise the function names are mangled. Even better put `#ifdef __cplusplus`\n`extern "C" {`\n`#endif` at the beginning of the header and `#ifdef __cplusplus`\n`}`\n`#endif` at the bottom.

Comment: I have tried including the header that defines binarion64_t and the function declaration itself inside and outside of extern "C" { } brackets with no success.

Comment: Huh. Then pleaes provide a [mcve].

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem; my attempts worked as I'd hope/expect.  HolyBlackCat's advice is good.

Comment: Added a minimal example as requested.

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR:

Use:

```
gcc -std=c99 -c binarion.c
gcc -std=c99 -shared -o libhanoi.so binarion.o -lm
g++ -std=gnu++11 -L. -lhanoi -o main main.cpp
```

---

Explanation:

You should be using `gcc` to compile a C file, `g++` is for C++. When you do `g++ -std=c99 -c binarion.c` the compiler gives you a hint with:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-std=c99’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
```

This means that you end up compiling your library as a C++ library. You can verify that by calling `readelf -s libhanoi.so | grep binarion`:

```
 9: 00000000000005da    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 _Z12binarion64_txx
29: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS binarion.c
44: 00000000000005da    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 _Z12binarion64_txx
```

As you can see, the function has been name-mangled, which is something C++ does, and C doesn't.

However, when compiling `main.cpp` you tell the compiler that `binarion_t` has C linkage:

```
extern "C" {
#include "hanoi.h"
};
```

So it is searching for unmangled `binarion_t` (instead of `_Z12binarion64_txx`).

Comment: This solution did not work completely. The out put of "readelf -s libhanoi.so | grep binarion" after running those commands shows unmangled names, but I still get the same undefined reference error. (This was on the exact setup in the question.)

Comment: @firstnamegklsodascb then you are either not compiling the same files as you posted here, or something is wrong with your compiler. Could you update your update your question with the exact files you used, the exact commands you compiled them with, and the output of `readelf -s libhanoi.so | grep binarion`?